# Xarray dimensions and coordinates restructuring

Tags: python-xarray

I'm analyzing displacement fields using the DIC engine (https://github.com/dicengine/dice). The Output of DICe is a netCDF4 dataset, which I want to evaluate in Python using the xarray data format. However due to the structure of the netCDF4 dataset I have troubles to work with the data and to make plots. The dataset is quite large, so workarounds using Pandas etc. are not an option.

```
xarray.Dataset {
   dimensions:
      time_step = 1689 ;
      num_nodes = 7713 ;
      ...
   variables:
      float32 DISPLACEMENT_X(time_step, num_nodes) ;
      float32 DISPLACEMENT_Y(time_step, num_nodes) ;
      float32 COORDINATE_X(time_step, num_nodes) ;
      float32 COORDINATE_Y(time_step, num_nodes) ;
      ...
```

**My problem is, that the 3D data (time_step, COORDINATE_X, COORDINATE_Y) is stored in only 2 dimensions (time_step, num_nodes)**

Does someone know how to efficiently adjust the dimensions?

Comment: You may want to take a look at at UXarray: https://uxarray.readthedocs.io/. It was developed to handle unstructured grids like what you are showing here. Other tools like Xgcm and Gridded may also be of use. You may also find the Pangeo Discourse forum to be a better place for this question: https://discourse.pangeo.io/